# DatasetNotFoundError: Dataset smartwatch_gestures not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I need to use the `smartwatch_gestures` from Tensorflow datasets and here is my code:

```
pip install --upgrade tfds-nightly

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_data,ds_info = tfds.load('smartwatch_gestures', as_supervised=True, split = 'train')

print(ds_info.features)
```

But, i get the following error:

```
DatasetNotFoundError: Dataset smartwatch_gestures not found.
```

Comment: Hi @AloneTogether, Can you help me with this ?

Comment: I can see there is no dataset with name smartwatch_gestures in tfds. you can download the smartwatch_gestures datset from [here](https://tev.fbk.eu/resources/smartwatch).Thank you.